# Way to add an Extension method?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Say I have a class called `LogHelper` and it has a static method called `GetLogger(string name)`.

Is there a way to add a static extension method that would just be `GetLogger()`?

I know that normally extension methods are static where they are declared, but is there a way to appear static on the class they are "Helping"?

Comment: Do you mean extension methods?

Comment: Yes, I do.  My Bad, I will edit.

Comment: You can not add extension methods to static types.  Extension methods can only be called from instances.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static ILogger GetLogger(this string value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then you could use like this:

```
string foo = "bar";
ILogger logger = foo.GetLogger();
```

Comment: But `GetLogger()` is not static on LogManager.  It is an instance method on a string.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
    public static ILogger GetLogger(string value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        return GetLogger("Default Value");
    }
```

This way when you called GetLogger() it would call GetLogger(string value) but with your default value.

Comment: I don't believe this will compile.

Comment: @Steven Sudit, you were correct the way I had it only works on constructors.

Comment: +1, this is apparently what the OP was looking for. I added a missing "return".

Comment: I think the OP wants this *without* adding that second method to the original class. However, that does not seem to be possible.

Comment: @Vaccano Why don't you want to add the second method?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it should work. log4net has an overload that accepts a Type, and you often want to name the logger after the fully qualified type name.

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Bar.Foo();
    ILog logger = foo.GetLogger();
}   

public static class LogHelper
{
    public static ILog GetLogger(this object o)
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(o.GetType());
    }
}

namespace Bar
{
    public class Foo {}
}

// Faking log4net
public class ILog {}
public class LogManager
{
    public static ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logger: " + type.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above prints "Logger: Bar.Foo".

P.S. Use "this.GetLogger()" if you want a logger for the current class (assuming non-static method).

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to extend static classes with extension methods, unfortunately...

(I'm assuming your LogHelper is static? At least that's what I understood so far.)

Answer (score 2):

Since what you want is impossible, why not fake it?

After all, it doesn't really matter if your parameterless `GetLogger()` method is on `LogHelper`. Just write your own static class, called `MyLogHelper` or something, and define the method there. The code would look like this:

```
public static class MyLogHelper
{
    public static ILog GetLogger()
    {
        return LogHelper.GetLogger("MyHardcodedValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see only one solution is to use [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), but unfortunately they appear only in C# 4.0:

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static ILogger GetLogger(string name = "DefaultLoggerName")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```