# Is there a way to add a static extension method on a class directly in Dart?

Tags: dart, extension-methods

I read in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629368/way-to-add-an-extension-method#comment3813313_3629368) on a similar question for C# that extension methods can only be called from instances. Is the same true for Dart? I'm trying to add a getter to the `Platform` [class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Platform-class.html) that will be called like so. `Platform.isDesktop`. However, this only works when calling an instance of the class, i.e. `Platform().isDesktop`, even if declaring the instance method as static. Why can't we add static members?

Code:

```
extension on Platform {
  bool get isMobile => Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS;
  bool get isDesktop => Platform.isWindows || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux;
}
```

Answer (score 74):

**Dart doesn't support static extension methods**.

An extension method acts like an instance method, not like a static method. There is currently no way to add static methods to a class from outside the class.

You can declare static methods in an extension, but they are static on the *extension itself* (you call them using `ExtensionName.methodName()`).

There is a discussion about adding extension static methods in https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723.